# Add image to label (or alongside it) using FormHelper

Tags: cakephp-3.0, form-helpers

I have an image that i want do display alongside with the label.

```
<?php
    echo $this->Form->input('ticketdays',['label'=>'Ticket days']);
?>
<img src="/img/help-round-button.png">
```

This is what happens now. I want do display it where the blue "circle" is.

[image]

How to achieve this? I accept any solution I can get. Already searched stackoverflow and Google and didn't find the answer.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
<div>
    <label>Ticket days</label>
    <span style="top:50%" class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span>
    <?php
        echo $this->Form->input('ticketdays', ['label' => false]);
    ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Works if `echo $this->Form->input('ticketdays', ['label' => false])` so it doesn't show two labels

Comment: If you need this structure in a number of places, you might think about creating a custom template for it. See [Customizing the Templates FormHelper Uses](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#customizing-the-templates-formhelper-uses) in the manual.